# Multiple lookups in a pipeline

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an aggregate call as listed below. I believe the massive delay is caused when the **roles** lookup happens because there are applicants, hired, and rejected people to lookup from the resources table. There are over 10,000 entries in the resource collection so the query is taking about 6 seconds. Is there something I am doing that is incredibly wrong here? I don't see how I can use indexes because all of the lookups are done by with the _id which is already indexed by default.

The applications, hired, and rejected fields are just arrays of object Ids e.g.

```
applicants: [
 ObjectId('asldkajsdlkj'),
 ObjectId('asldkjaoksdjak')
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.It was taking 6 seconds on an M0 instance and is no faster on an M10 instance.

```
return db.collection('projects').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     agents: ObjectId('SOMETHING')
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agents",
      localField: "agents",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agents"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agencies",
      localField: "agency",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agency"
    }
  }, 
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "roles",
      let: { "roles": "$roles" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$roles" ] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from:"resources",
            let: { "applicants": "$applicants" },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$applicants" ] } } }
            ],
            as: "applicants"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "resources",
            let: { "hired": "$hired" },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$hired" ] } } }
            ],
            as: "hired"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "resources",
            let: { "rejected": "$rejected" },
            pipeline: [
              { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$rejected" ] } } }
            ],
            as: "rejected"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "agents",
            localField: "hiring_agent",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "hiring_agent"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "roles"
    }
  }
], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Comment: MongoDB is designed to store "boiled" data. It means, in project collection, you need to store **redundant** information to transform into desired result. Crossing different collections will penalize perfomance... I think there is nothing to do here

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. I’ll be happy to make your answer accepted if you put it.

Comment: Can you provide sample data?

Comment: The resources are just objects, first name last name kind of stuff. But there are 10,000 resources now and will likely be 3-5x more than that. I've started migrating to the solution you mentioned and if I still have issues, I'll switch to a relational database.

Comment: Wait a sec... The solutuon is more simplier. The problem is on `$lookup` with `let - pipeline`...

Comment: I see what you're saying now, but the projects are loaded often and since multiple people may be working on them at once, the data is refreshed on page load. Therefore I think its better not to have to run four lookups even if there isn't a let pipeline.

Comment: Try to use given query, it has better performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB is designed to store "boiled" data. It means, in `project` collection, you need to store redundant information to transform into desired result.

In your case, performance decreases with inner `$lookup` with `let - pipeline` for `role` collection due [to this error](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-41171).

Try to change:

```
db.collection('projects').aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
     agents: ObjectId('SOMETHING')
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agents",
      localField: "agents",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agents"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "agencies",
      localField: "agency",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "agency"
    }
  }, 
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "roles",
      let: { "roles": "$roles" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: [ "$_id", "$$roles" ] } } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from:"resources",
            localField: "applicants",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "applicants"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "resources",
            localField: "hired",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "hired"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "resources",
            localField: "rejected",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "rejected"
          }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "agents",
            localField: "hiring_agent",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "hiring_agent"
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "roles"
    }
  }
], {
  allowDiskUse: true
})
```

Comment: I went with your original answer. Since the resource information won't change that often (at least the information I actually required from this pipeline, e.g. name and avatar) it's best to keep a copy of the relevant information in the array rather than the ObjectIds. I will try the above suggestion whenever I can't keep a copy due to constant changes.